# G Suite email forwarding with SRS

Tags: g-suite

I'm forwarding email from my G Suite domain to an Outlook.com email address. This worked perfectly fine until earlier this month. All forwarded emails go directly to junk, because SPF is failing.

For example: grouponmail.nl -> G Suite -> Outlook.com. In Outlook.com the email headers are:

```
Authentication-Results: spf=softfail (sender IP is 108.177.16.23)
 smtp.mailfrom=bounce.r.grouponmail.nl; outlook.com; dkim=pass (signature was
 verified) header.d=r.grouponmail.nl;outlook.com; dmarc=pass action=none
 header.from=r.grouponmail.nl;compauth=pass reason=100
```

So the G Suite server is still using Groupon's from address when forwarding which causes the SPF to fail. I can't find any option to rewrite the from address when creating a new route. All options are listed here: https://support.google.com/a/answer/6297084.

How can I rewrite the from address when forwarding email using G Suite (also known as SRS/Sender Rewriting Scheme)?

Answer (score 0):

I am using split delivery in Google Workspace aka. G Suite to forward all mail not belonging to existing accounts on Google Workspac to my own mail server, so I have a similar scenario of sorts. Consequently, I came across the same problem: Google does not do SRS on these forwarded emails, and there is no way to enable it in the settings.

The answer to your question after my extensive research is: Google does not support Sender Rewriting Scheme (SRS) an we should request this as a feature, as we are not the first paying Google customers experiencing SPF problems when forwarding emails. ([source](https://support.google.com/mail/thread/108914085/does-google-domain-based-mail-forwarding-support-sender-rewrite-to-pass-spf-checks?hl=en))

I do not have enough reputation to post this as comment, so this remark goes in-line:

My workaround on my private postfix server was to disable SPF checking on emails forwarded by google.com, which in my postfix configuration meant adding this line to /etc/postfix-policyd-spf-python/policyd-spf.conf :

```
Domain_Whitelist  = google.com
```

Answer (score 0):

We are not alone. There's an issue filed already but apparently GSuite doesn't care about these issues:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/244619242